# What's the best match iTunes version for iPhone 2G (first generation) now?

Tags: iphone, itunes

My iPhone 2G (first generation) can't be recognized by the current iTunes 11. (Tried both DFU mode and recovery mode but failed.)

So whats the best match iTunes version (and where can it be downloaded) for iPhone 2G so that this ancient guy be can recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a 'best match' version.

The earliest version that will support an iPhone 2G to iOS 3.1.3 [the latest the phone can use] is [iTunes 9.2.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1056)

But I know of no reason it shouldn't be recognised by the latest iTunes. v12 still recognises my old 3G & even has no trouble with my seriously ancient iPod Photo from 2004, which is still going strong as my in-car player.

I've seen suggestions to completely uninstall & reinstall iTunes - but no conclusive proof it really does anything useful.

I also came across this whilst Googling - don't know if it still works, but might be worth a look - [You Can Now Install iOS 5 On iPhone 2G/3G And Old iPods Without Jailbreaking](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2012/01/19/you-can-now-install-ios-5-on-iphone-2g-3g-and-old-ipods-without-jailbreaking/)